# SSIS job fails to connect to database using trusted connection and login with sysAdmin permission

Tags: sql, ssis, windows-authentication

I have a SSIS job that uses an XML configuration file containing a connection string to connect to a database where the full SSIS configuration properties are stored/managed.  I do this so I can have the same compiled SSIS package deployed to DEV, TEST, and PROD and alter the values in the SSIS configuration tables in a database for each environment.  The connection string in the XML file executes as a trusted connection assuming the SQL Agent user which has sysadmin permission and works on other setups and somehow it is failing in this SSIS Package with this error:

Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login failed for user '{my sysadmin user account}'.".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot open database "{my config database}" requested by the login. The login failed.".  End Error.

This a SSIS Package developed using VS 2022 and deployed to SQL Server 2022.

I thought that maybe somehow the SQL Agent user account was locked out but I checked and that is not the case.  I even logged into the server with that account through SSMS just after it failed and it logged in just fine into the database in question so I am perplexed why it fails using SQL job for this SSIS Package.  I expected that the SSIS job would execute with the SQL Agent user account which is a sysadmin and for that account to get the configuration values from the database without providing explicit access to the database.  When I tried to provide explicit access to the database the job failed with the same error.  I altered the connection string to use a SQL UserId/Password and gave that user permission to the database and it worked fine; it just will not work for the SQL Agent account and a trusted connection.

Any ideas on where I might look for the problem as to why it is failing to login as a sysadmin to a database?  Can I see anything more about what is actually happening using Extended Events perhaps and if so, what events?

Here is the xml config file contents: (removed personal values inside curly braces)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><DTSConfiguration><DTSConfigurationHeading><DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedBy="{author name}" GeneratedFromPackageName="{PackageName}" GeneratedFromPackageID="{8F41A38C-EFD8-48AB-8D6D-F48E66A1162B}" GeneratedDate="11/3/2023 2:59:17 PM"/></DTSConfigurationHeading><Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[Config].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue>Data Source={data server name};Initial Catalog={config database name};Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;</ConfiguredValue></Configuration></DTSConfiguration>
```